# How to use ionic model to view and edit data? is it good approach?

Tags: ionic2, ionic-view

I have saved data in sqlite. Now i want to edit data. I want to create a model and give list of saved records in it. when user click on any row display on model it will go into edit mode . Is it good approach or should i create another page ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to provide them with edit button/icon and when they click on edit button you can change all labels to Text edit format.

reasons -

- This will be a mobile app, hence user needs to touch on the screen to scroll/change to another page. if the user mistakenly clicks on the label then the label will get change to edit mode and I guess that's bad user experience.
- Every time you need to save the changes when the user clicks on the label (more database operation for a single word change).

Instead of this just provide edit button/icon, when they click on edit button, make the same page change to edit mode and show them save button (replace edit button).

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the link with the data model. However, when it comes to design, it is better if the user clicks on a row to open a new page.

If you want to switch to an edition mode, then you need a button dedicated to this feature.

Think "WYSIWYG" --> "What You See Is What You Get".